# Conjunction after "such that"

Tags: conjunctions, mathematics, predicate, such

I am writing a mathematical paper. Consider a sentence like the following:

"we choose a function F such that formula (1) holds and the quantity F(x) is complex"

It seems to me that the sentence is a bit hard to read, because the "and"  may be seen as the beginning of a new sentence.

**Is there a better way to write such a sentence?**

Thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: Such that P and Q are what???

Comment: They are two properties associated to the object X (I edited the question).

Comment: You choose an object such that color and weight???

Comment: I think this would be easier to answer if you showed the full sentence rather than using P and Q as placeholders.

Comment: I edited the question, writing an explicit example of sentence I have in mind.

Comment: Presumably, the audience for this paper will be mathematicians so they will be reading the sentence from that perspective and take the "and" as a logical operator. You could make it more explict with "such that (a) _formula (1) holds_ and (b) _the quantity F(x) is complex_".

Comment: There is a formal notation for indicating that a function maps a real [domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_of_a_function) to a complex [codomain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codomain). That saves you from having to use the *and* entirely. It may not be appropriate depending on the audience, and it requires typesetting [special characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_symbols_by_subject). Written out—F denotes a complex function of a real variable. Choose F such that (1) is satisfied.

Comment: Why do you think "and" starts a new sentence?

Answer (score 0):

How about:

'We choose a complex function F(x) such that the formula (1) holds.'

'such that' is a phrase that introduces a result clause/Adverbial clause.

To be able to answer correctly, we need to first understand what you are talking about; and that's why I think this question would be better served in "Math Stack Exchange."